# bs4Dash using moduleServer()

Tags: shinymodules, golem, bs4dash

I have an issue with using modules with bs4Dash. I have created a ShinyApp with modules using golem which I created from my previous ShinyApp.
I have no issue in using `input$dark_mode == TRUE` or `if (input$dark_mode)` if it is a single app, for example,

```
if (input$dark_mode)
{ 
p1 <- plotly::ggplotly(plot01 + ggplot_dark_theme)  
p1
}
else { 
p1 <- plotly::ggplotly(plot01 + ggplot_light_theme) 
p1
}
```

But when you use module it returns `Error: argument is of length zero`

Has anyone seen error like this? Is there a fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

I have fixed this by using `reactiveValues()`and `observe()` functions in `app_server.R`

```
# Global
  global <- reactiveValues()
  observe({global$dark_mode <-  input$dark_mode})
```

And linking `global` to the plot modules.